# Using Match Patterns In Backround.js Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a chrome extension project, but cannot get match patterns to work so it covers everywhere the user goes past the domain. For an example so if the user went to https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en To have the code execute again there. Is this possible to do in the background.js file?

```
  chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function() {
      alert("This is my favorite website!");
  }, {url: [{urlMatches : '*://www.google.com/*'}]});
```

I have tried using a variable for '*://www.google.com/*' for example below:

```
var site = "*://www.google.com/*"
will not let me pass this into either url: 'site'
or {url: [{urlMatches : 'site'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onCompleted) `urlMatches` doesn't use **match patterns**, it uses **regular expressions** with [RE2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt).

For `*://www.google.com/*` you can simply switch to `hostEquals`:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(info => {
  console.log(info);
}, {
  url: [{hostEquals: 'www.google.com'}],
});
```

Note that in JavaScript `'site'` is a literal string that's not related to the variable `site`.